# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.Consts

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am converting my project in  Studio from eclipse.I am sending image in multi part to sever using **httpmime 4.5.1** jar file. This is my code.it gives me NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.Consts error.

Please help me.

This is my code.

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>() {



                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {

                   // setting progress bar to zero
                    progressBar.setProgress(0);

                    super.onPreExecute();

                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                    // Making progress bar visible

                    // updating progress bar value
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

                    txtPercentage.setText(progress[0] + "%");

                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {



                    for (i = 0; i < allPath.length; i++) {



                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                txtCount.setText((i + 1) + "/"
                                        + allPath.length);

                            }
                        });

                        allPath[i] = selected.get(i).sdcardPath;





                        String responseString = null;

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                                Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

                        try {

                            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                                    new ProgressListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void transferred(long num) {
                                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                                        }
                                    });

                            File sourceFile = new File(
                                    compressImage(allPath[i]));

                            // Adding file data to http body
                            entity.addPart("tag", new StringBody(
                                    "productAdd"));

                            // Adding file data to http body
                            entity.addPart("image",
                                    new FileBody(sourceFile));

                            entity.addPart(
                                    "seller_id",
                                    new StringBody(
                                            CommonUtilities
                                                    .getSellerId(getApplicationContext())));
                            entity.addPart(
                                    "shop_id",
                                    new StringBody(
                                            CommonUtilities
                                                    .getCurentShopId(
                                                            getApplicationContext())
                                                    .toString()));
                            entity.addPart(
                                    "product_pId",
                                    new StringBody(
                                            CommonUtilities
                                                    .getMaxProductId(
                                                            getApplicationContext())
                                                    .toString()));

                            entity.addPart("cat_id", new StringBody(cat_id));


                            entity.addPart("product_image", new StringBody(
                                    allPath[i]));

                            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();

                            httppost.setEntity(entity);


                            // Making server call
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient
                                    .execute(httppost);

                            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine()
                                    .getStatusCode();

                            if (statusCode == 200) {
                                // Server response
                                responseString = EntityUtils
                                        .toString(r_entity);
                            } else {
                                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                                        + statusCode;
                                flagForError = true;

                            }

                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            responseString = e.toString();
                            flagForError = true;

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            responseString = e.toString();

                            flagForError = true;
                        }

                        if (flagForError == false) {

                            updateAfterResponse(responseString);

                        } else {



                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    uploadDialog.cancel();
                                    dialogForError();
                                }
                            });

                            task.cancel(true);
                            break;

                        }
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        });

                        if (i == allPath.length - 1) {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    txtCount.setText("Done");
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        // return responseString;
                    }
                    return null;

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    // showing the server response in an alert
                    // dialog

                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    // if (i == (allPath.length - 1)) {

                    if (uploadDialog.isShowing()) {

                        uploadDialog.dismiss();
                    }


                }

            }.execute();
```

and it is giving me error

```
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.elsner.orderlite, PID: 10320
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     a`enter code here`t java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.Consts
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody.<init>(StringBody.java:147)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.elsner.sellerproduct.CustomGalleryActivity$2$1.doInBackground(CustomGalleryActivity.java:311)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.elsner.sellerproduct.CustomGalleryActivity$2$1.doInBackground(CustomGalleryActivity.java:221)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
12-10 17:35:58.710 10320-10340/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 3):

in bundle.gradle use

```
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

> To do multipart POST calls, you need to get three additional Apache
>   open source projects: Apache Commons IO, Mime4j, and HttpMime. You can
>   download these projects from the following web sites: Commons IO:
>   http://commons.apache.org/io/ Mime4j: http://james.apache.org/mime4j/
>   HttpMime: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi (inside of HttpClient)

Comment: but httpmime jar file working fine with eclipse. and StringBody class using that org.apache.http.Consts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sdk version 23, you have to add to your gradle:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    ...
    **useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'**
    ...
}

Comment: useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' dosen't have Classes called, org.apache.http.ContentType,org.apache.http.Consts etc.